# Set ImageView src from HashMap

Tags: android, android-imageview, drawable

I have a HashMap for weather condition icons as static method in a class.
in my adapter I get the value and setImageResource with this, but faced with exception.I'v searched a lot and find this solution, but with exception. here is part of my HashMap:

```
static String getWeatherConditionList(Context mContext, String code) {
    HashMap<String, String> weatherConditionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    weatherConditionMap.put("0", String.valueOf(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thunderstorm)));
    weatherConditionMap.put("1", String.valueOf(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tstormrain)));
return weatherConditionMap.get(code);
```

}

and for imageView I used this:

```
imageForcast.setImageResource(Integer.getInteger(PublicMethods.getWeatherConditionList(mContext, code)));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code.

1. Everytime you call `getWeatherConditionMap()`, `weatherConditionMap` is recreated.
2. It is a bad idea to put drawables in hashmap.
3. Do you really need `static` statement?

You could change it like this.

```
private static HashMap<String, Integer> weatherConditionMap = new HashMap<>();

private static void createHashMap() {
    weatherConditionMap.put("0", R.drawable.thunderstorm);
    weatherConditionMap.put("1", R.drawable.tstormrain);
}

static int getWeatherContion(String code) {
    return weatherConditionMap.get(code);
}
```

At first you call `createHashMap()` and, in calling method,

```
imageForcast.setImageResource(getWeatherCondition(code));
```

Of course, you could exclude `static`.

---

### Update

`createHashMap()` should be called once. If you cannot find the exact position to put that function, check if it is called before in getter function.

```
static int getWeatherContion(String code) {
    if (weatherConditionMap.size() == 0) {
        createHashMap();
    }
    return weatherConditionMap.get(code);
}
```

Or, maybe you don't need the HashMap if you just want the mapping resource for code.

```
static int getWeatherConditionMap(String code) {
    switch (code) {
        case "0":
            return R.drawable.thunderstorm;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm new in android programming. I did what you said and I have a question when createHashMap method called?

Comment: You can call the function in onCreated() in Activity, or in getWeatherCondition(). But If you call the function in getter function, you have to check that create function is called before.

Comment: Thanks of your solution, I know HashMap isn't good solution but as I told I'm new. Can you suggest me another solutions?

Answer (score 0):

First you should always add any exception you got to your question and explain the flow of your code. 
Second why do you cast the int into a string and back, maybe instead try use a `HashMap<String,Drawable>` and call:

`imageForcast.setImageDrawable(drawable)`;

Comment: Thanks of your attention. Really I saw it in one of the solutions and I wanted to test it maybe solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should store drawable in Map

```
public static Drawable getWeatherConditionList(Context mContext, String code) {
      HashMap<String, Drawable> weatherConditionMap = new HashMap<>();
      weatherConditionMap.put("0",mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thunderstorm));
      weatherConditionMap.put("1",mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tstormrain));
return weatherConditionMap.get(code);
}
```

you must set Image with Drawable

```
imageForcast.setImageDrawable(PublicMethods.getWeatherConditionList(mContext, code));
```